# How to create/merge panel data?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, panel

I have two data frames. Dataframe "weather" looks like this:

```
weather<-data.frame(Date=c("2012-04-01","2012-04-02","2012-04-03","2012-04-04"),Day=c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"), Temp=c(86,89,81,80))

Date       Day       Temp    
2012-04-01 Sunday     86
2012-04-02 Monday     89
2012-04-03 Tuesday    81
2012-04-04 Wednesday  80
```

And, dataframe "Regularity", looks like this:

```
Regularity<-data.frame(Date=c("2012-04-02","2012-04-04","2012-04-03","2012-04-04"),EmployeeID=c(1,1,2,2),Attendance=c(1,1,1,1))

Date        EmployeeID Attendance
2012-04-02           1          1
2012-04-04           1          1
2012-04-03           2          1
2012-04-04           2          1
```

I want to create a panel dataframe in R of the form:

```
Date       Day       Temperature EmployeeID Attendence  
2012-04-01 Sunday     86              1         0
2012-04-02 Monday     89              1         1
2012-04-03 Tuesday    81              1         0
2012-04-04 Wednesday  80              1         1
2012-04-01 Sunday     86              2         0
2012-04-02 Monday     89              2         0
2012-04-03 Tuesday    81              2         1
2012-04-04 Wednesday  80              2         1
```

I have tried the merge and reshape2, but in vain. I will be very grateful for any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dual `merge`, along with `expand.grid`, like this:

```
merge(weather, 
      merge(Regularity, 
            expand.grid(Date = unique(weather$Date), 
                        EmployeeID = unique(Regularity$EmployeeID)), 
            all = TRUE))
#         Date       Day Temp EmployeeID Attendance
# 1 2012-04-01    Sunday   86          1         NA
# 2 2012-04-01    Sunday   86          2         NA
# 3 2012-04-02    Monday   89          1          1
# 4 2012-04-02    Monday   89          2         NA
# 5 2012-04-03   Tuesday   81          1         NA
# 6 2012-04-03   Tuesday   81          2          1
# 7 2012-04-04 Wednesday   80          1          1
# 8 2012-04-04 Wednesday   80          2          1
```

The `expand.grid` step is to get all the combinations of "Date" and "EmployeeID" that would be required for a full dataset.

You can easily replace the `NA` values with "0" in another step.